# What should I do about people approving terrible edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In the suggested edit review queue, I came across [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7851712). This seems like a textbook bad edit - it adds poorly worded noise content to an already poorly worded question without improving any of the flaws that existed previously, and breaks the code formatting as well as introducing superfluous bold text. However, I'm disappointed to see that two out of two reviewers before me have approved this edit. I feel like this ought to be a duplicate question, but I was unable to find a specific answer to this question when I searched - is there something I can/should do (besides highlighting it here) to deal with these bad reviews?

Comment: The user suggesting doesn't seem to have many *good* edits, and quite a few *bad* ones (but still sadly approved).

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link - I was sure something on this topic must exist, but just couldn't seem to find the right combination of terms to search for it.

Comment: "Please do the needful" I always get a kick from that phrase.